# On bundle install showing error : `fetch_http': bad response Service Unavailable 503

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

In command prompt when I run `bundle install`

I got an error showing there

```
 `fetch_http': bad response Service Unavailable 503
```

If anybody else faced such error before?

Comment: if you have proper Internet connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ruby, 
I suppose there will be some problem with your Internet connection. Please recheck your connection.

Or any plugin/gem is unfetchable.

**503** ->**Service Unavailable** 
    That means:
Server cannot respond due to maintenance or overloading. For example, a servlet might return this header if some thread or database connection pool is currently full. Server can supply a Retry-After header.